# Running a loop that has a function inside it

Tags: php, function, for-loop

I have a problem trying to run a code inside the loop, my loop consist of a function.

Here is my coding:

```
$new = array(1,2,3,4);
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++){
$val = $new[$i];



function myfunction($value) {   
    //Do something
}

echo $val;
}
```

The problem is the code outputs only the 1st value in my array. I am very confused, am I not suppose to declare a function inside the loop?

Comment: Why is there a function in your loop?

Comment: as the correct answers have already been given, a short notice as to why this happens: your code tries to redefine the function 3 times, which is not allowed in PHP. A tip: use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the start of your script or set it in the php.ini while learning / developing - with this setting, you would have seen something along the lines of "fatal error, trying to redefine function myFunction in..."

Comment: `for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++){ $val = $new[$i];` can be written as `foreach ($new as $val) { ...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code ends up with Fatal error, since at the second iteration it tries to redeclare function `myfunction`. That's why it is printing only first value of array.

In order to avoid that fatal error you can check if that function has been already defined using [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) function like this:

```php
$new = array(1,2,3,4);
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++)
{
    $val = $new[$i];
    if(!function_exists('myfunction'))
    {
        function myfunction($value) {
            //Do something
        }
    }
    echo $val;
}
```

PHP is a scripting language and it is syntactically correct to declare a function inside for loop or inside if statement, but it is a bad practice and can cause a lot of errors afterwards.
The best way is to declare a function outside loop, and, if needed, call it from within a loop like this:

```
<?php
function myfunction($value) {
    //Do something
}

$new = array(1,2,3,4);
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++)
{
    $val = $new[$i];
    myfunction($value); //may you was intended to pass $val here?
    echo $val;
}
```

Comment: I feel like ``if(!function_exists('myfunction'))`` should be built into the language spec. If someone wants to declare a function inside a loop (which is allowed and *has interesting uses*), they shouldn't have to resort to the same boilerplate every time.

Answer (score 6):

Don't declare the function inside the loop, declare it before the loop and then call to it inside the loop with `myFunction($value);`

Comment: "declare it before" ... or after ;-)

Comment: Psh, just following programming best practices, you typically want to declare your functions first.  But true, PHP will let you declare it after. =P

Answer (score 5):

the function should be in a separate procedure

```
$new = array(1,2,3,4);
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++)
{
   $val = $new[$i];
   myfunction($val)
   echo $val;
}
```

then this is your function

```
function myfunction($value) 
{   
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I knew I was missing something small, I have wasted an hour trying to figure dis out, I feel so dum rite now :-D

Answer (score 1):

- Declare the function outside of the loop
- either return a value from the function, or let the function output data

For example:

```
function myfunction($value) {   
  //Do something
  echo $value;
}

$new = array(1,2,3,4);
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++) {
  myfunction($new[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that is not the right way to do it...
first declare the function outside the loop, then call the function in the loop

```
function myfunction($value) {   
    //Do something
}


$new = array(1,2,3,4);
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++){
   $val = $new[$i];
   myfunction( $val);  //call function where u wanted... here (in your  case)
   echo $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to print out the first 4 elements of the array.
do something like this

```
function myfunction() {   
  $new = array(1,2,3,4);
  for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++){
    $val = $new[$i];
    echo $val;
  }
}

myfunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the function outside the loop

```
function myfunction($value) {    
    return ($value + 25); // an example
}

$new = array(1,2,3,4); 
for($i = 0; $i < count($new); $i++){
    echo myfunction($new[$i]); 
}
```

Also you should set the loop from 0 to the end of the array, so if you'll have more than 4 entries in the array the code should be ok

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an anonymous function instead:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=3; $i++) {
    // code
    $myFunction = function($value) { /* code */ }
    $myFunction($val);
    // code
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You are not suposed to declare the function inside a loop...